# Can I add a wait when using aws ecs run-task command in my deployment pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ecs, circleci, aws-fargate

I am using CircleCI for my CI/CD along with CodeDeploy. I would like to run an `ecs run-task` command and would like the task to complete before moving on to the more intricate deployment stages, which we use CodeDeploy for, and is triggered through the CircleCI config. In a previous version of the aws cli the `--wait` flag was an option for this, but is not an option in aws version 2+. Are there any other simple alternatives that people are using to get around this?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `aws ecs wait` capability in the CLI. Note that this is the same in [version 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/wait/index.html#available-commands) of the CLI and [version 2](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/wait/index.html), there was never a `--wait` for ECS tasks in the core AWS CLI as far as I'm aware.

Specifically, after starting the task and getting the task ID returned from the `run-task` command, you would use `aws ecs wait task-stopped --tasks <task-id>` to wait for the task to be done/stopped.

Answer (score 3):

Adding my solution here thanks to Mark B's response.

```
TASK_ID=$(aws ecs run-task \
--profile staging \
--cluster <cluster-name> \
--task-definition <task-definition> \
--count 1 \
--launch-type FARGATE \
--network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[$SUBNET_ONE_STAGING, $SUBNET_TWO_STAGING, $SUBNET_THREE_STAGING],securityGroups=[$SECURITY_GROUP_IDS_STAGING],assignPublicIp=ENABLED}" \
--overrides '{"containerOverrides":[{"name": "my-app","command": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bundle exec rake db:migrate && bundle exec rake after_party:run"]}]}' \
| jq -r '.tasks[0].taskArn') \
&& aws ecs wait tasks-stopped --cluster <cluster-name> --tasks ${TASK_ID}
```